# How do I extract a date from an Excel file to SQLite3

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

I'm trying to extract some data from an Excel file to a database.
Therefor I'm using the following code:

```
import os
import sqlite3
from win32com.client import Dispatch
#----------------------------------------
# get data from excel file
#----------------------------------------
XLS_FILE = os.getcwd() + "//test.xls"
ROW_SPAN = (16, 17)
COL_SPAN = (2, 7)
app = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = True
ws = app.Workbooks.Open(XLS_FILE).Sheets(1)
exceldata = [[ws.Cells(row, col).Value 
         for col in range(COL_SPAN[0], COL_SPAN[1])] 
         for row in range(ROW_SPAN[0], ROW_SPAN[1])]

#----------------------------------------
# create SQL table and fill it with data
#----------------------------------------
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE exceltable (xyz TEXT, xyz TEXT,
                                      xyz INTEGER, xyz TEXT)''')
for row in exceldata:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO exceltable VALUES (?,?,?,?)', row)
conn.commit()
```

This works well for extracting normal data types such as Integer, but I can't extract the date data type to the database like that. The dates are stored as DD.MM.YYYY in the Excel file.
Any suggestions how to solve that Problem?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are interested in the solution, I got it running with this code:

```
for r in range(15, sheet.nrows):
    Value1 = sheet.cell(r,1).value

    if sheet.cell(r,15).value == "":
        Value2 = "No Date included"
    else:
        a1 = sheet.cell(r,15).value
        Value2 = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1,book.datemode))
```

Therefor you need to import xlrd and datetime and it's good for saying which value of the Excel file should stand in which column of the database. The If-clause describes the extraction of a date data type from Excel to SQlite3